# Windows phone 7 TCP network client

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, tcp

Basically, I've written a windows phone 7 client, which is supposed to receive a very long string from the server.  However, there seem to be some limitations on the phone networking code, and am having trouble figuring out how to do this.  The following is the code I am using:

```
public string Receive()
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        // We are receiving over an established socket connection
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = _socket.RemoteEndPoint;

            // Setup the buffer to receive the data
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                        response = response.Trim('\0');
                }
                else
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();
                }

                _clientDone.Set();
            });

            // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
            _socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);

            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

As it stands, this will only accept the first N bytes of the message and return that... any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would try to redesign your code to be appropriately async - working round the fact that WP7 doesn't offer synchronous IO by building your own isn't nearly as clean as embracing the asynchrony.

Secondly, you're assuming that you only need a single `ReceiveAsync` call to get the whole data. Assuming your using TCP, that's a *stream-based* protocol. You'll need to either add some sort of delimiter or length prefix, or keep reading until the other side closes the connection if that's the way your protocol works.

(Any reason you're not doing this with HTTP and `WebClient` or `WebRequest`, by the way?)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the response.  Basically I have a server that needs to send large quantities of data to the phone, continuously.  Then the phone needs to parse it and display it.  How would you suggest to go about doing that in the simplest way?  As to WebCline/WebRequest... hadn't heard of them until just now :)

Comment: @ElfsЯUs: Is this data split into "messages" of some kind? How do you know when you've "finished" receiving? If you really need to stream then WebClient may not be the best approach... but if you can change so that you could basically poll (with long-polling on the server) and get "all the recent messages since X" then it may well make life simpler.

Comment: I have N objects, and I need to update their position on the phone remotely K times per second.  So basically, I never "finish" sending the data.  At each time step I serialize the list of objects, send them across the network, deserialize their new positions, and display them on the phone screen.  So the each time step is split into a separate message, but am sending them virtually continuously.

Comment: @ElfsЯUs: Okay, so how do you expect the client to break the stream into messages? Do you have delimiters, length-prefix etc?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would try to redesign your code to be appropriately async - working round the fact that WP7 doesn't offer synchronous IO by building your own isn't nearly as clean as embracing the asynchrony.

Secondly, you're assuming that you only need a single ReceiveAsync call to get the whole data. Assuming your using TCP, that's a stream-based protocol. You'll need to either add some sort of delimiter or length prefix, or keep reading until the other side closes the connection if that's the way your protocol works.

(Any reason you're not doing this with HTTP and WebClient or WebRequest, by the way?)